# influence of soft iron in magnetic lenses

Tags: electromagnetism, lenses, microscopy

I'm currently working as an intern in a research group which is specialized in transmission electron microscopes. 
I'm reading a book from David B. Williams and C. Barry Carter : Transmission electron microscopy.

The electron beam in the microscope is focused via electromagnets for example : circular coils, magnetic quadrupoles, etc ... 
If we focus on circular coils, the authors of the book explain that there is a soft iron core all around the coil's wires except for 2 small holes. In all the schemes I have seen of a megntic lens, it seems that every thing is happening as if there was a magnetic field only around this soft iron dipole.

From what I know, the soft iron piece has no reason to "cancel" the field in the coil (apart from the dipolar setup) as a superconducting material would do.

My question is the following : What is the qualitative effect of the soft iron piece and how is it confining the magnetic field? 
Is there a reference where I can find a quantitative descprition of the system ?

I hope my question wasn't too messy. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: No, you don't want to 'cancel' the field - you want to increase it! Start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_core and go from there.

Comment: The quantitative description of these systems is given by the magnetostatic part of Maxwell's equation plus the empirically measured magnetic properties of the iron used for the design of these magnetic. Unfortunately, the solution of these systems is extremely messy and requires numerical approaches for anything that comes even close to a useful engineering design. There is nothing trivial about magnetic lenses, I am afraid.